# DDD and ticking data as an input

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, system.reactive

I am looking at building an application where one of the main inputs to the system will be live ticking values.

I was hoping to use DDD as I believe that I have enough complexity in my model to warrant it but am a little unsure how to structure things. Repositories are the way to get at data, but every reference I see defines them as pull based. ie When I want data I ask the repository for it and it will return an entity/aggregate root for you. Im my case I will have repositories for setting up my aggregate root, but then I need the entities within to be updated without any request from me.

My solution to this was to define a domain service that the aggregate root calls to initiate the ticking. Do people feel that this is the right way to go?

If the service is the right thing to do, what are peoples opinions on its responsibility. Should it know about the aggregate root and mutate its state with the ticking entities or should it just blindly push data and the aggregate root itself know that it is receiving data in this way listen for it and update accordingly when data is received?

Any pointers / comments / flames are grateful.

Comment: You sue C#. What about you get a copy of SQL Server for developers and check the subsystem they just added that does exactly that? Ignoring those design patterns may not be smart. not saying you can not do it different, more like you ahvea hugh example right in front of you.The keyword is "StreamInSight".

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I am already happy with my tech stack of using Rx to receive my streamed inputs. The question is about how I should design things using ddd not in sql server

Comment: AH? I di not tell you to use it, but to look at their API. You ask for how to implement it, and I post you at a ssetm doing exactly that in .NET to LEARN. If you dont want to learn, why do you ask?

Answer (score 0):

Rx is a way of abstracting away state and incidence by using combinators whose states are isolated from each other. The only places where you have mutability in Rx are when you use Subjects. So generally mutating the object and sending notifications that it has mutated isn't very functional (what about re-entrancy?)

If you have a number of different services a Pub/Sub system is good. Publish can happen from a multiple points and can be combined into a stream and there can be many subscribers on a particular stream.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the concepts from DDD work quite nicely with Rx. While Asti makes a good point of favoring immutability, ultimately most applications need mutation somewhere. I find that if you can isolate where your mutations happen then this is a good middle ground.

Following on from this, I would suggest that sequences of data (Rx streams) should contain immutable data. Having sequences of mutating data can be very difficult to work with.

With this in mind, we can now have an Arch where the *Repository* returns you your *Aggregate Root*. Your Aggregate Root can call *Services* which provide sequences of data, ideally *Value types*. Your Aggregate Root can now apply what ever domain logic to the incoming data (which may include mutating it's own state).

So I would imagine your work flow would look something like

- Consumer requests AggRoot from Repository
- Repository uses Factories to either create or re instantiate the AggRoot
- AggRoot is injected with a service when created
- Consumer then invokes some functionality on the AggRoot
- This makes a call to the underlying service to get a sequence.
- The AggRoot subscribes to the sequence and processes that data.